# Packaging a header library, header dependencies

Tags: dependencies, packaging

When packaging a library A that contains of headers (similar to boost), those headers may have `include` statements to another header library B in them. Consequently, when building an application with A, the headers of B also need to be present in the system.

What is the correct way to include this dependency in B in the `control` file?

Answer (score 1):

In the block for the `A-dev` binary package, you'd add `B-dev` to the `Depends` list.

(Real examples would really help us to help you)